# catching on-click event of dynamically allocated id

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

`element.find('#id1').on('click', function(){ ...` does not work.

I am looking for code to do the ABOVE.

/* The below text/code is my problem in deeper context.*/

I can do the same with `$('#id1').on('click', function(){ ...`  problem is i'm using ng-repeat to dynamically allocate id to element

```
.set(ng-repeat='item in items').my-directive
  button(id='id{{$index}}') press me
```

so interestingly

`element.find('#id1')` works but `$('#id1').on('click', ....` does not work.

The following is some of my-direcitive code

```
$('button').on('click', function() { alert('hi');} // works

$('#id0').on('click', function() { alert('hi);} // does NOT work
```

more over

```
$('button').on('click', function() { 

  element.find('#id1').css('width', 1000); // Also Works

}
```

It which means using 'element' you can refer to $scope of ng-repeat where as you can't with jQuery ie
using simple $('#id1') of jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamically allocate id :

```
$('#YourWrapperID').on('click','#id1' , function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `.click` function.

```
$( "#id1" ).click(function() {
```

Take a read here:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: please read a few more lines of the question. There is a technical problem i'm facing, clubing it with ng-repeat.